# Why am I unable to prevent the animation queue from stacking without breaking my code?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, queue

I am attempting to use jquery and CSS to animate the buttons of a navigation sidebar I am using to signify which button is selected when the mouse is hovered over each.

Currently, my code for the CSS appears as such:

```
#navbutton {position:relative; width:178px; height:35px; border:1px #FFF solid; z-index:+3; font-family:'Capriola', sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-align:center;}

#navbutton.button {color:#77D; background-color: #F0B0D0;}
#navbutton.button_hover {color:#66C; background-color: #FCF; padding:10px;}
```

And my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#sidebar div").mouseenter(buttonHover) 

function buttonHover(){
    $(this).stop().switchClass('button','button_hover',500);
    }

$("#sidebar div").mouseleave(button)

function button(){
    $(this).stop().switchClass('button_hover','button',500);
    }   

});
</script>
```

Before I added the .stop() to each part of the animation, the animation queue would stack up for each time the mouse was moved over each button and then removed.  Now that the .stop() has been applied, however, if the mouse is moved away from a button during its animation, the button will freeze and remain in its mid-animation state, unable to be fixed by being hovered over until the page is reloaded, rather than reverting to its original mouseleave state.

From everything I've read, this should not be the case.  Might anyone be able to tell why my animation queue becomes broken once the .stop() is applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.stop(true,true)` to make it go to the end of the current animation, otherwise it will just stop wherever it is.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Looks like that did the trick.  I removed the .stop from the mouseleave portion of the code in order to remove the jerky effect caused by each button immediately cutting off its animation as the mouse was taken off, but adding (true,true) to the hover portion fixed the problem with the queue stacking up.  Thank you very much, Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code which seems to be working in firefox. Actually your right it breaks if you move the mouse off or on halfway through the animation. Looks like the other guys answer is the solution.

```
<html><head>

<style type="text/css">
:button {position:relative; width:178px; height:35px; border:1px #FFF solid; z-index:+3; font-family:'Capriola', sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-align:center;}
.effect {color:#77D; background-color: #F0B0D0;}
.effect_hover {color:#66C; background-color: #FCF; padding:10px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(":button").mouseenter(buttonHover) 
function buttonHover(){
    $(this).stop().switchClass('effect','effect_hover',500);
    }

$(":button").mouseleave(button)
function button(){
    $(this).stop().switchClass('effect_hover','effect',500);
    }   

});

</script>

</head><body>

<input type="button" value="Test Button">

</body></html>
```

Comment: Actually Kevin's solution stop(true,true) works provided it is applied to both the mouseenter and mouseleave instances